# Create a process generator

Tags: c

I have a process (`nameprocess.c`) which make some stuff.

I need to create another process (`nameprocess-generator.c`) which continue to generate the process `nameprocess.c` until a countdown arrived at `0` or a while arrived at `0`.

Do I have to use an `execv` or a `fork`?

Comment: You'll have to use both.

Answer (score 1):

You use both. Using `execv()` by itself will just replace the running
process with another one.

First you use `fork()`. This creates a clone of the running process. You
now have two processes running the same code. How do you tell them
apart? By the return value. The original process (“parent”) gets a
return value of the new process ID (`pid`), and the new one (“child”)
gets a return value of 0.

So, the original process keeps doing whatever, while the new one calls
one of the `execv` functions to replace itself with a different process.

You can see some sample code that uses `fork()` in an old answer of mine,
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200795).